# How to bind boolean to combo box

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, boolean

I'm facing a problem regarding database and combo box. I got a table name "station" and inside the table are columns, station name and seats. The column seats are set as "BIT". I use a combo box for user to select 'Yes' or 'No' but how to convert them to BIT and store into database. This is my codes for the create.

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            string[] stations = StationNameList();
            station creStation = new station();
            creStation.Station1 = txtStation.Text;
            creStation.Seat = cbSeats.SelectedItem();
            if (stations.Contains(txtStation.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Station is already been created. Please enter a new Station.");
            }
            else
            {
                Setupctx.stations.AddObject(creStation);
                Setupctx.SaveChanges();
                txtStation.Text = "";
                cbSeats.SelectedIndex = -1;
                MessageBox.Show("New Station Has Been Created.");
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is at here:

```
creStation.Seat = cbSeats.SelectedItem();
```

They prompt me cannot convert from string to bool. 
Any help?

Comment: use condition if yes set 1 else 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

same as

```
creStation.Seat = cbSeats.SelectedValue=="Yes";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool.TryParse(cbSeats.SelectedValue, out creStation.Seat);
```